# Error fitdist “should not have NA or NaN values”

Tags: banco-de-dados, r

Venho tentando ajustar as distribuições e lognormal nos dados e venho enfrentando o seguinte erro:

> --should not have NA or NaN values--.

Segue abaixo os códigos:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(readxl)
library(survival)
library(muhaz)
library(fitdistrplus)

dados = readxl::read_excel('dados1.xlsx')
dados$Estagio = dados$Extensão
dados$Estagio[dados$Extensão=='SEM INFORMAÇÃO'] <- NA
dados$Estagio[dados$Extensão=='IN SITU'] <- NA

dados$Grau.de.Instrução[dados$Grau.de.Instrução=='FUNDAMENTAL'] <- 'ENSINO FUNDAMENTAL'

dados <- data.frame(dados)
head(dados)
attach(dados)
x11()
hist(dados$tempo_vida_meses)

####################################
cbind(table(Estado.Civil),prop.table(table(Estado.Civil))*100)
cbind(table(Raca.Cor),prop.table(table(Raca.Cor))*100)
cbind(table(Grau.de.Instrução),prop.table(table(Grau.de.Instrução))*100)

######################################################################
Weibdist = fitdist(dados$tempo_vida_meses, "weibull")
Expdist = fitdist(dados$tempo_vida_meses, "exp")
lgnormdist = fitdist(dados$tempo_vida_meses, "lnorm")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um função que`fitdist` chama, `startarg`, resulta em erro se houver algum valor igual a zero no vetor inserido em `fitdist`.

```
if (distr == "weibull") {
    if (any(x < 0)) 
      stop("values must be positive to fit an Weibull  distribution")
    m <- mean(log(x))
    v <- var(log(x))
    shape <- 1.2/sqrt(v)
    scale <- exp(m + 0.572/shape)
    start <- list(shape = shape, scale = scale)
```

Valores iguais a zero, como existem no vetor, criam `NA`s na entrada de outras funções, mesmo que no vetor inicial não exista nenhum `NA`.
Mesma coisa para `lgnormdist`. Os valores de entrada tem que ser positivo.

Aí você usa algo como o `filter` do pacote `dplyr` ou

```
entrada <- dados$tempo_vida_meses[dados$tempo_vida_meses > 0]
```

Comment: Excelente resposta. Mas aí entra uma discussão teórica: se estes dados são amostrais e 0 é um resultado possível para eles, será que as distribuições weibull ou log-normal deveriam ser uma opção para a sua modelagem? Na minha opinião não. Talvez fosse necessário procurar outra distribuição de probabilidade, como a weibull inflacionada de zeros.

Comment: Reforçando a observação do Marcus Nunes: a resposta foi ótima por identificar a causa do problema; mas Breno, se a função de probabilidade que está usando não aceita zeros e os dados possuem zeros, busque uma mais adequada. O modelo deve ser ajustado aos dados, nunca o contrário.